# Substring with Findstring SSIS

Tags: ssis

can someone help me to correctly formulate the expression that I am using to extract a value within a string:

(2222) 010A07_TM

I need to extract only the expression 010A07, at the moment I am using the following, but it hasn't worked:

(DT_STR,50,1252)(SUBSTRING(FIELD_NAME,FINDSTRING(FIELD_NAME," ",1) + 1,FINDSTRING(FIELD_NAME,"_",1) - 2)))

PLIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter of substring function is the string length. The second index must be subtracted from the first index.
`FINDSTRING(FIELD_NAME,"_",1) - FINDSTRING(FIELD_NAME," ",1) -1`

The final code will be as follows:

`SUBSTRING(FIELD_NAME,FINDSTRING(FIELD_NAME," ",1) + 1,FINDSTRING(FIELD_NAME,"_",1) - FINDSTRING(FIELD_NAME," ",1) - 1)`

Comment: Can you help me how the following expression would look in ssis format, plis:

SUBSTRING(FIELD,charindex('_',FIELD,charindex('_',FIELD)+1)+1,LEN(FIELD))

I want to get only "Hello. GDDD"

(0000) 02450_98552_Hello. GDDD

Comment: You can use this code: `RIGHT(FIELD,FINDSTRING(REVERSE(FIELD),"_",1) - 1)`